# Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.0 crashed on windows 10

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I have installed Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.0 64bit on Windows 10, My jdk version is 1.8_60 64bit. When I run Jaspersoft Studio, It crashed and show error message "Jaspersoft Studio.exe has stopped working", without any clue to solve. Is there anyone knows where did JaspersoftStudio store it's log file? or maybe someone have already know the solution? i'll appreciate for any clue, Thank you.

here is my Jaspersoft studio.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-data
@noDefault
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
features/jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u121/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run as administrator? Did you check the log file?

Comment: @AlexK Yes I run as administrator. I couldn't find the log file, do you know where is the log file?

Comment: You can look at *Jaspersoft Studio.ini* file and *log4j.properties* (at folder TIBCO\Jaspersoft Studio-6.x.final\)